# How to fix: $ne is not allowed in this atlas tier

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I am getting a error message **$ne is not allowed in this atlas tier**.

I want to exclude an _id from an array. Only items that are not associated with the selected watchSession id will be included.

```
router.get('/session/:id', ensureAuth, async (req, res) => {
    let idUser = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user.id)
    let idWatch = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)
    try {
        const birds = await Bird.aggregate([
            {$project: {name: 1, count: 1, _id: 1, user: 1}},
            {$match: {user: idUser} },
            {$unwind: '$count'},
            {$ne: {'count.watchSession': idWatch} }
        ]);
}
res.render('birds/session', { birds })
catch (err) 
})
```

The relevant schema.

```
const CountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    count: { type: Number },
    watchSession: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'WatchSession'
    }
})

const BirdSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    comName: { type: String },
    count: [CountSchema]
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('Bird', BirdSchema)
```

the other schemas I have

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ user: { type: String  } })
module.exports = mongoose.model('Bird', BirdSchema)

const WatchSessionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ location: { type: String } })
module.exports = mongoose.model('WatchSession', WatchSessionSchema)
```

I don't see away to exclude items using aggregate() so I tried to use populate(), but am getting the full array.

```
const birds = await Bird.find({user: req.user.id})
            .populate( 'count', {
                "watchSession": {$ne: req.params.id} }
             )
            .lean()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: As for your aggregate pipe: you're using $ne as a stage. That's why you're getting the atlas error. You need to use $match stage ```{$match: {'count.watchSession': {$ne: idWatch}}}```

Comment: This worked, thanks